# iOS app development - property not found on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just started using XCode to try to make iOS applications. I tried to complete Apple's own tutorial (A to-do list). It went very well until the last step/s here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1

I connected the Save and Cancel buttons to the AddToDoItemViewController (Control n drag).

Then, when i want to tell AddToDoItemViewController to create an item only when the user taps the Save button, i got errors.

I tried to write this method in ToDoListTableViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

8 issues appear. For example, in the first if-statement: "Property 'saveButton' not found on object of type ToDoListTableViewController*".

Also a similar issue just under it but instead of "saveButton" it says "textField". I did the imports as suggested.

Help appreciates!

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to say by  sender != self.saveButton?

Comment: sender here it's segue itself. It cannot be equal to button

Comment: are you sure you don't have a typo in `saveButton` property?

Comment: Can you show the code that where saveButton and textField is connected?

Comment: @anton that isn't correct. If you trigger the segue from a UIbutton in IB then sender will be the button. If you trigger it via `performSegueWithIdentifier` then sender can be any object

Comment: Sure but if you'd like to catch exactly the button you should not use (id)sender but (UIButton*)sender

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the tutorial documentation.

Where https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html says that you should "In the project navigator, select ToDoListTableViewController.m." you really should be following those steps in "AddToDoItemViewController.m".

So just drop that code block in 'AddToDoItemViewController.h' instead of 'ToDoListTableViewController.m'.

Comment: Side note, why on earth was the OP down voted?  I'm new to stackoverflow.